# how to transform density object to function

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to use the output of  the `density()` object as a function (to do many things as derivative, integrate on specific interval, evaluate at specific point,...)

To be clear, let's take an example:

```
a=c(1,3,10,-5,0,0,2, 1, 3, 8,2, -2)
b=density(a)
```

I would like some transformation of `b`

```
f=some_transformation(b) # transformation I don't know
is.function(f) # answer must be "TRUE"
```

so that I can evaluate the density at any point

```
f(1.2) # evaluate density at 1.2
```

compute its derivative

```
Df=D(body(f), "x") # derivative of f
Df(1.2) # derivative at 1.2
```

and do other R stuff as if `f` is a function.

Comment: Isn't the density at any single point by definition 0?

Comment: @Dualinity: No. You may be confusing density with probability, and if that is what you are thinking of then it only applies to continuous distributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `approxfun`.

```
a <- c(1,3,10,-5,0,0,2, 1, 3, 8,2, -2)
b <- density(a)
f <- approxfun(b, rule=2)
is.function(f)
f(1.2)
```

Since it is not defined by a formula, 
you cannot use `D` (symbolic differentiation) 
to compute its derivative.
You can estimate it numerically, though.

```
library(numDeriv)
df <- function(x) grad(f,x)
curve( f(x),  lwd=3, xlim=c(-10,10) )
curve( df(x), lwd=3, xlim=c(-10,10) )
```

Comment: You can do an (approximate, numerical) integral: `integrate(f,0,5)` for example.

Comment: Thank you. 'approxfun' return exactly what I want. Because of approximation, I will consider numDeriv.

Answer (score 0):

`D` takes an expression, not a function as its first argument. It is for doing symbolic calculus, not finding the gradient of numeric values.  You can numerically calculate the derivative of `b` wrt `x` using.

```
with(b, diff(y) / diff(x))
```

Here's a visualisation of the gradient to give an example of how you might use it.

```
librray(ggplot2)

gradient_data <- with(
  density(a), 
  {
    data.frame(
      dy_by_dx = diff(y) / diff(x),
      x        = x[-1] + x[-length(x)] / 2
    )
  }
)


(gradient_plot <- ggplot(gradient_data, aes(x, dy_by_dx)) +
  geom_line()
)
```

If you want to evaluate the function at any point, then use `approx`.

```
with(density(a), approx(x, y, xout = -8:13))
```

The answer will be more accurate if you increase the `n` argument to the `density` function.